# How to show all possible solutions with lp solve with r

Tags: r, optimization, binary

My idea is to start using lp solve in order to solve a linear programming model. As a result, I studied the lp function and his components. 
However, one thing which is not clear to me is how do I display all possible optimal solutions using lp solve in R without my variables be binary?
I would appreciate an easy example to better understand.

Thanks,
David

Comment: There is no easy way of doing this.

Comment: What do you suggest to do alternatively?

Comment: For different reasons "all possible solutions" in an LP is a difficult concept anyway. So in most cases we have to live with one solution. Of course you can do sensitivity analysis and things like that.